# What Reverse Engineering Tools Are Available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, tools

I would like to know ,what are different Reverse Engineering Tools , that work on linux. I was using OllyDebug on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[edb](http://codef00.com/projects#debugger) is a debugger for Linux that aims to be like OllyDbg (the author even says so).  It uses Qt and boost.

[A bit more info here](http://www.gamelinux.org/?p=36)

It is available in Ubuntu's repositories in 18.04 (Bionic) and later as the `edb-debugger` package (not to be confused with the package `edb`, which is a database for emacs).